# Changing Illustrator File to Emogi

Tags: html, utf-8, adobe-illustrator

I created an illustrator document that I want to change into an emogi. However, I have failed to convert it to UTF-8 code. Is there a way of doing this? Below is the image.
[Airtel 5G logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kRDL.png)

I have tried various websites but I keep coming up short.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your goal. Perhaps you can make a font with this symbol and use it as one of the characters of the font (as soon as you install the font on your system, I doubt though that it will work on smartphones). But Adobe Illustrator can't make a font. You have to use another app (Fontographer, FontLab, etc) or some converter (probably there are online ones).